# Carregar url com $.ajax e uso de token

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-service

```
O código seguinte não carrega url. O que está errado?



    var token = "XfdfdffddfdfdfferrrrrrrrrrreeeeeeeeeeJ777K";
    var url = "https://producao-talcoisa.com/api/Produto/PesquisarConteudo/";

    $.ajax({

        url : url,
        type : 'GET',
        contentType : "application/json",
        beforeSend: token,
        error : onError,
        success : onSuccess

    });




tokenSession =  null;

var setHeader = function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('tokenApp', token);
    if (token.tokenSession != null) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('token', token.tokenSession);
    }
};



    function onSuccess() {

        console.log("sucesso");
        // ToastMessage.showMessage("Sucesso");

    }


    function onError() {
        console.log("Erro");
        // ToastMessage.showMessage("Erro");
    }
```

Comment: Qual erro retorna na requisição?

Comment: Cara, tem certeza que a requisição é `GET` e beforeSend recebe `token`? Tente colocar `POST` e mandar o `token` como post e veja o que dá.

Comment: coloca data: '&token=' + token, ai vai ficar assim https://producao-talcoisa.com/api/Produto/PesquisarConteudo/&token=XfdfdffddfdfdfferrrrrrrrrrreeeeeeeeeeJ777K

Comment: Mudei para POST mas continua.

Comment: se e para passar o token pela url então concatena `url: url + token`,

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente sua requisição é `POST`, e não faz sentido você passar uma string em `beforeSend`

Tente assim:

```
$.ajax({

    url : url,
    type : 'POST',
    contentType : "application/json",
    data: {token:token},
    error : onError,
    success : onSuccess

});
```

Comment: Ainda retorna erro

Comment: Qual erro retorna?

Comment: Retorna  frase "erro" que fica no metódo onError() conforme código colocado no post.

Comment: Veja o erro no console, aba network.

Comment: Acredite, não aparece nada!

Comment: Habilite os erros pelo servidor. Se for PHP, adicione isso no inicio do arquivo: error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');